# UITableViewのCustom Cellの高さが調節できない

Tags: swift, xcode

以下のようなコードを作成し、ビルドすると、画像やラベルが見切れてしまって正しく表示されませんでした。

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import Foundation


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let label : UILabel = UILabel()
        
        label.text = sections[section]
        
        return label
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return values[section].count
    }
    
    //高さを指定
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 94
    }
    
    //cellがタップされた時の処理
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        // セルの選択を解除
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        // セルを取得する
        let cell: CustomCellTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCellTableViewCell

        // セルのタグにindexPath.rowを持たせる
        cell.tag = indexPath.row
        
        cell.cellLabel?.text = values[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        
        cell.cellImageView?.image = UIImage(named: "testImage.jpeg")
        
        return cell
    }
    
    var sections = [""]
    var values = [["Test-A","Test-B","Test-C"]]
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 94
        
        self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

**CustomCellTableViewCell.swift**

```
import UIKit

class CustomCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
    
    @IBOutlet weak var cellImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellDateLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

XCode上での設定
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

実際に表示されたTableVieｗが以下の通りです。
顔の画像が見切れていたり、文字が見切れて表示範囲が非常に小さくなっていることがわかるかと思います。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

どのようにしたら、正しくXCode上の表示のように余裕を持ったスペースで表示できますでしょうか？

※追記
Constaintは使用せずに、Autoresizingで位置などは調整しようとしています。
以前作ったプロジェクトではAutoresizingのみで問題なくCustomCellを運用できていて、それを参考にしながら作っているのですがなぜか高さがおかしくなっています。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: Storyboardのスクリーンショットを拝見すると、Auto Layoutのconstraintを設定していないようですが、実際はどうですか？

Comment: Constraintは使用していないですが、Autoresizingの設定は行っています。ConstraintやAutoresizingでどのような箇所がおかしい可能性があるとしたらどこでしょうか？